# Window Resize Handle Event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Certain elements of my application have custom resizing events, which all work. However, they are messed up by one case:

When hovering over the border of the window, so that the cursor becomes the resize handle, and you click (but do not drag), the elements resize incorrectly, and my handlers are not fired.

I've looked for such an event but cannot find anything that matches. I'd like to simply make a handler for this event to avoid glitchy resizing of my elements.

I'm using C#/WPF, with .NET 4

xaml for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="XHealth.MainWindow"
    Name="mainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridTemplateSample"
    xmlns:XH="clr-namespace:XHealth"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"

    SizeChanged="update_size"
    Title="XHealth"  Loaded="Window_Loaded" WindowState="Normal" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow"  MinWidth="650" MinHeight="648" Width="Auto"  VerticalAlignment="Top" DataContext="{Binding}" PreviewKeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
```

Event handler:

```
public void update_size(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
{
        if (resultsTab.IsSelected){
          Grid.SetRowSpan(dataGrid1, 2);
          Grid.SetRowSpan(dataGrid2, 2);
        }
}
```

This handler performs as intended, but does not trigger when the resize handle is not dragged, which leads me to believe clicking the resize handle is a different event.

Also, this only happens once - once my resize handler takes effect, clicked the resize handle has no effect.

Comment: post the relevant XAML and code. otherwise it's all speculations.

Comment: Dude, I have no idea what you're talking about. This is not the correct way to do layout in WPF. You don't handle size events in WPF. Actually you don't handle any events as a general rule unless strictly needed. WPF layout system is resolution-independent and provides much happier ways to achieve all kinds of layouts. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the right way to do it in WPF.

Comment: [link](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1246/examplei.png) In the first window, the datagrid fills out as intended, but when the border is clicked, you get the second picture. This is the datagrid in one row (*) and another empty row (also *). This was done to avoid the third picture which is what happens when the datagrid gets populated with large datasources, and the window would stretch based on the content in the datagrid.

Comment: That could be resolved by not putting any `*` in the Grid. Also, if the Window is set to `SizeToContent`, you should only `SizeToContent=Width` to prevent the window from scaling endlessly. Remove all the event handlers stuff, that's hack. Post the revelevant XAML so I can understand better.

Comment: @user1663203 Ok I posted it as an answer. Be sure to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer:

That could be resolved by not putting any * in the Grid.

Also, if the Window is set to `SizeToContent`, you should only `SizeToContent=Width` to prevent the window from scaling endlessly.

Remove all the event handlers stuff, that's hack.