# How do I force my window to re-size?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an auto-sized application **user control** in WPF (Height="Auto" Width="Auto"). When a bunch of elements inside it are resized, the windows stays the same rendered size. How do I force it to resize? I have tried this line `Application.Current.MainWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;` in the function that resizes the components inside the window. The compiler gives me an error that there is no object associated with this call. I have tried this line `MainWindowBorder.Height = Double.NaN;` to trick it to resize. No luck either.

Comment: Did you try window.height -= amount you resized your elements

Comment: You could definitely keep track of how much everything is changing and manually do it how @Master117 mentioned. It can be a bit tedious to get the code in order, depending on how many controls you have and how they change, but it would definitely work.

Comment: All of the elements inside are re-sized automatically. I collapse or make visible elements inside a series of grids, so I can't manually change the size without tedious calculations. The window contains the collection of these auto-resized grids.

Comment: IIRC, you need to make the window non-user-resizable.

Comment: If it's a grid i think you need to stick it into a panel or something similar for auto to work. Not 100% sure.

Comment: This may be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922955/window-resize-handle-event

Comment: Does Application.Current.MainWindow exist since you get an "no object associated with this call" error?

Comment: No, it does not exist. I do not know why. The MainView is created.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038879/refer-to-active-window-in-wpf

Try to get the window of your UserControl? A Control can't exist on its own.

Comment: That doesn't work either. It still comes up with no object associated.

Comment: This works better. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236905/access-parent-window-from-user-control

Answer (score 1):

Use SizeToContent in XAML

```
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You cannot put that in the XAML. I have tried putting that in my loading page code behind (MainView()) but it gives me the error: Does not contain defintion for SizeToContent,. Also, if you read my question above, I stated that I have tried this in the code behind.

Comment: You cant? not like this?

<Window x:Class="CustomDialogSample.SettingsDialog"
  ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"
  SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0470__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/SizeToContentWidthAndHeight.htm

Comment: Ah the problem is that I am doing this for a user control, not a window.

Answer (score 1):

If all the inside controls can be resized but the only one thing to resize is Window, How about this simple approach? Hope this helps..

```
int mycurrentscreenwidth = 1366;
int mycurrentwindowwidth = 1366;

var screen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
var screenwidth = screen.Width;

if (Convert.ToInt32(screenwidth) < 1366)
{   
    double calculate_scalefactor= Convert.ToInt32(screenwidth) / (double)mycurrentscreenwidth;
    double newwidth_tobescaled = mycurrentwindowwidth * calculate_scalefactor;

    this.Width = newwidth_tobescaled;
}
```

Comment: have to resize usercontrol ? same logic might be applied.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the window of your current user control, see:

[Access parent window from User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236905/access-parent-window-from-user-control)

Then use:

```
Window yourParentWindow = Window.GetWindow(userControl);
yourParentWindow.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
```